# Why do my views in storyboard vary in height / not show the navigation bar?

Tags: xcode, layout, window, size, storyboard

I have quite a large storyboard with many views, a lot of them do not display at the correct size or even have a navigation bar. Is this some kind of bug in XCode?, because they all look fine when simulated or built to a device.

Thanks

Comment: here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nK7wF.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced it lot of time below solution works every time.

**Try This One:**

1. Select the StoryBoard you are facing problem

2. Goto Attributes Inspector -> Simulated Metrics -> Size -> There are four options(default is inferred) 

3.Select or switch between options other then default(repeat it twice or more if needed) then resize your views and controls to fit your selected screen size.

**According to me this happens because:**

Sometimes inferred (size) behaves as if its an 3.5 retina screen but our storyboard size is retina 4 full screen or vice-versa

**Best Practice to avoid such problems :** 

When you start working with storyboard first select appropriate size you want to work with (3.5 or 4 full screen) then only you should set your views or controls.

Comment: I have seen you screen shot - you have used 3.5 and 4 full screen size - how can you do that - this storyboard will never function properly

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when embedding Container Views into the same View Controller.

With three Container Views embedded I found that Xcode auto-sized two of them when I selected "Apply Retina X.X Form Factor" but the size of the third was left untouched.

**Solution**
In the parent View Controller the third Container Viewer was missing constraints. Adding those constraints got every thing straight. (I also had to size the Container View to fill its parent Controller Viewer)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple step. After selecting View Controller, go into your Simulated Metrics and select size and place it on iPhone 4-inch and then select Orientation and place it to Portrait and there you have it. Your main storyboard metrics are fixed. Again this is very important to know that this will not mess up anything your height or width in your project